# Windows Phone: Upload file to ASP Server?

Tags: asp.net, silverlight, windows-phone-7, post, upload

I need to upload a file to my server. I have no prior knowledge to server side programming and need some advice I can understand. I have my file (JPEG Image) in a byte array in my Windows Phone app. I now need to upload it to my server. I currently have a sample that uses HttpWebRequest with post, but I do not know how to handle the data in that post from the asp page. If you could explain how to do this it would be great, but I am open to any alternatives, providing they can be used with Windows Server.

The code I am currently using: ('b' is the byte array for the file)

```
var uri = "http://www.masonbogert.info/mcode/default.aspx";
        var request = HttpWebRequest.Create(uri);
        request.Method = "POST";
        request.ContentType = "image/jpeg";  // Change to whatever you're uploading.
        request.BeginGetRequestStream((result1) =>
        {
            using (Stream stream = request.EndGetRequestStream(result1))
            {
                stream.Write(b, 0, b.Length);
            }

            request.BeginGetResponse((result2) =>
            {
                var response = request.EndGetResponse(result2);
                // Optionally handle the response.
                var responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();
                Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new readstreamdelegate(readstream), responseStream);

            }, null);


        }, null);
```

Remember, when it comes to ASP and any other server side programming I have no prior knowledge, so please explain!

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use the "WebClient" class for getting it. More information you can get there: "http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient(v=vs.80).aspx".

Answer (score 0):

Please see this page: http://nediml.wordpress.com/2012/05/10/uploading-files-to-remote-server-with-multiple-parameters/#more-234